# Adapt Gradle of Module to experimental Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-experimental

Which changes do I need for this Gradle from one module if I am sing the experimental tools gradle in my top gradle project?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion = 22
    buildToolsVersion = '22.0.1'
}

apply from: 'rules.gradle'
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentations available at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental , I believe it should be something like this:

apply plugin: "com.android.model.application"

model {

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    }
```

}

If you have repositories mentioned in the gradle file at the top of the project then it should pick it up from there.